# sudo apt update error: "E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list"

Tags: command-line, package-management, sudo, spotify

```
$ sudo apt-get update                      
N: Ignoring file 'some-ppa.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'some-ppa.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I started getting this error after I used this command while installing Spotify:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/some-ppa.list
```

I used some solutions given in the site but it didn't apply in my case.

Here is the content of my `sources.list`:

[image: Screenshot of sources.list]

Comment: Post the contents of the sources list.

Comment: We don't know what OS & release you're using (which is needed to correct many flaws in sources), plus we cannot see the files mentioned unless you show them to us. The `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory is empty on new installs; so those files were added by a user on your system with `sudo` privileges. The line number in the error message tells you the line that needs correction.

Comment: i added source.list in the body as a img,

Comment: Not as an image never show pics of text include the text in the body of the question.

Comment: Line 1 of this file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list` contains an error which you haven't provided. You didn't provide that file, but that's the only line which has a "E:" error on it.  That is the line that needs fixing and file to fix it.

Comment: Please post the source.list as text. Images of text are not searchable.